# Windows 10 won't boot : INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

When I restarted my computer this morning, I saw that BSOD with a `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` message, preventing me from booting Windows.

I tried many things :

- The automatic repair takes quite a long time but finds nothing.
- When I try go to the screen allowing me to choose some boot options (F1->F9), I try to boot in safe mode (F4) and at the moment I press the key, there is a black scree then half a second after I get back to the choosing screen.
- Eventually, when I try the automatic repair, I get this message: 
  `Windows\system32\drivers\nvstor.sys is corrupt` (it seems that nvstor is a driver for a nForce motherboard, but it isn't my case).
- When I use a bootable disk of Windows to use the console, I open the automatic repair log it says an update was not working.
- I tried many console commands like `Bootrec /fixmbr, Bootrec /fixboo, Bootrec /scanos Bootrec /rebuildbcd` without success.
- My OS is on an SSD and my data is on a HDD, so I tried to disconnect the HDD and only keeping the SSD with no more success.

I think it is related: the reason why I restarted my computer was because I was unable to access the "`hosts`" file and, in fact, I was able to access none of the critical system files despite the fact I was the Administrator with an elevated rights console. Indeed, it's really strange.

Do you have any suggestion about how to fix this?

Comment: Re-seat the SSD. If that doesn't work, boot off another drive (likely will have to install an OS first) then try drive recovery tools on the SSD.

Comment: That doesn't work either. :c

Comment: Maybe reset the CMOS? Or a bad CMOS battery?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have the same problem, and the only things I can think of and that I haven't tried yet are resetting/fresh install...

Comment: Nop, unfortunately I had to do a fresh install. :(